# Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

My code is this but not working

```
<?php
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    $sk = socket_connect($sock,"10.0.1.43","1234");
    socket_set_nonblock($sock);

    while (1) {        
        sleep(2);
        $buffer=socket_read($sock,512);
        echo "Buffer = $buffer \n";
        echo "Last Error = ".socket_last_error($sock).socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock))."\n";        
    }        
?>
```

It display error:

unable to read from socket [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected 
PHP Stack trace:
Buffer =
Last Error = 107Transport endpoint is not connected

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to **accept a connection** first! Inside your `while()` loop, do another `while()` like this:

```
while($client = socket_accept($sock)) {
    $buffer=socket_read($client, 512);
    echo "Buffer = $buffer \n";
}
```

It should work, as you intend.

Comment: When adding you're code to above, we've got: "`Warning: socket_accept(): unable to accept incoming connection [22]: Invalid argument in /share/web/gps/gateway2.php on line 9`", where line 9 is referring to `while($client = socket_accept($sock))`.

Comment: I believe you didn't define `$sock`. That would be something like this `$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`

Comment: Yes! I've figured this out myself, basing on PHP Example on [PHP.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php). I even posted corrected (some bugs fixed) and updated example, but idiots at PHP.net have removed it without any notice.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the client socket is not connected.

What is protocol '0'?  Are you sure that '0' is TCP on your system?
Not sure if you can change the socket block/non-block state after a connect() - never tried such a thing.
If $sk is false, what is the last error?
Is the server at 10.0.1.43:1234 reachable with TCP?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: My ip is reachable that i have tested.Now it worked fine by editing some code.but still it is not working when i run this url from another system.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in a comment to previous answer, you can find fine example of solving this problem on [PHP.net Examples Page](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php). In the main article you'll find a good example, how to make a listener without error, you're refering to, for one client and in javier's notice below, how to have the same for multi-client purpose.